# Reading Specific String from a line in a file

Tags: python, file

I have file looking like this:

```py
face LODRxERROR
{
  source   R/com/int/LRxAMEexception.csv

  contains R/saqf/LAWODRxERROR.ddf
  contains R/bld/LAWODRxERRORtyp.h
  contains R/bld/LAWODRxERRORtyp.hpp

  requires LAWODRxERR
}
```

At the moment I'm able to read a specific line and store it. But I need to be more specific. Instead of reading the whole line. I would like to read only the file name no the directory. So, instead of reading `R/bld/LAWODRxERRORtyp.hpp` I would like to read only `LAWODRxERRORtyp.hpp`

Here is my python code so far:

```py
    with open(file) as scope:
        for line in scope:
            line = line.strip()
            if line.startswith('contains') and line.endswith('.h') or line.endswith('.hpp'):
                scopeFileList.append(line.split()[-1])
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [`os.path.basename()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) to get only the file-name from a path:

```py
from os.path import basename

with open(file) as scope:
    for line in scope:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('contains') and line.endswith('.h') or line.endswith('.hpp'):
            path = line.split()[-1]
            scopeFileList.append(basename(path))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as f:
    data = [line.replace("\n","").split('/')[-1] for line in f.readlines() if '.' in line]
```

---

**Output:**

```
print(data)

['LRxAMEexception.csv',
 'LAWODRxERROR.ddf',
 'LAWODRxERRORtyp.h',
 'LAWODRxERRORtyp.hpp']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You can use the re.search to find the file names from a path

```
with open('new_file.txt') as file:
     for line in file:
             line = line.strip()
             if line.startswith('source') or line.startswith('contains'):
                    file_names = re.search('/(.+?)\/((\w+)\.\w+$\Z)', line).group(2)
                     print(file_names)
```

O/P:

```
'LRxAMEexception.csv'
'LAWODRxERROR.ddf'
'LAWODRxERRORtyp.h'
'LAWODRxERRORtyp.hpp'
```